# Can be Windows 8 drive with UEFI boot cloned trivially?

Tags: windows-8, uefi, disk-cloning

Due to lack of disk space, I need to replace bootable 128 GB SSD drive with 256 GB unit.

***Is it as simple as creating disk image of drive and restoring it on another drive or should I expect any troubles with UEFI boot?***

I asked at PC shop who are willing to clone the drive (cloning needs m-SATA cables which I don't have), but they admitted they did not do this before with UEFI-boot drives.

I have already read related Q&A's present on this site, they are for Windows 7.

Comment: Just get the computer shop to disable the secure boot options where they'll be able to boot a cloning solution. Once the clone is complete the re-enable secure boot. They may have to run Windows Startup Repair if Windows doesn't boot straight away but 9/10 this fixes everything.

Comment: Secure Boot really has nothing to do with it, unless you're using an emergency boot disk for the cloning and that disk doesn't support Secure Boot. What's directly relevant is the various GUIDs used as serial numbers on the disks. If the cloning software replicates those GUIDs, then everything should work. If not, then the NVRAM entries that point to the boot loader will be invalid, and the boot may fail. Chances are it will still boot through a fallback boot entry that usually exists, but details depend on how the OEM set up the original disk (assuming it's a pre-installed Windows).

Comment: @BigChris - thank you, see below how it went... Disabling and re-enabling secure boot was not necessary.

Comment: @RodSmith – many thanks for details provided. I asked the shop to be careful about disk serial numbers, if possible. I'm not sure whether they finally were able to clone them or not. Perhaps it can be understood from what happened, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, it seems to be good. But there were some *scary* rough edges along the way:

- First boot thrown "unable to boot" error. I was asked to choose a bootloader and after I did, PC instantly turned off after few secods.
- I started PC using recovery button and from menu I selected "Normal Startup". There were no bootloader issues after this point.
- Windows startup was much longer than usual. After logging into my user account, ***Windows and Office lost their activation***. I restarted the PC.
- Windows 8 login screen came de-personalized (default theme), and desktop started showing build number. I started calling Microsoft activation hotline but in few minutes, Windows re-activated itself with activation date sent to current date. I restarted the PC again.
- Now everything went smoothly as weeks before. Personalization and Windows activation were in place again. I re-activated Microsoft Office.

I think that activations were lost because failed motherboard was replaced only 10 days before 1 SSD was replaced and 1 SSD in machine was re-imaged. If I waited 2-3 months before taking actions on SSD's, activations would be kept.